# How to remove autogenerated route path segment in Typo3

Tags: typo3

After following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtBmim7pc0o), my page was generated with the segment "autogenerated-3". In the tutorial, they had no such problem.

This is a clean installation version 10.4.17.

How do I get rid of this route segment?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the left pane, go to Site Management > Sites and then once on that page, remove the auto-generated slug from the entry point URL (depicted in red):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you created the root pages before adding a site configuration manually (deployment) it could happen that there are multiple, "invisible" site configuration files for the same root page.

Have a look in the `config/sites/` folder.
If there are one or more "autogenerated-xxx-xxxxxxx" folders you can delete them (make a backup if you are unsure about them).
After that clear all caches (best in Maintenance -> Flush Cache)

That's it.Your `autogenerated-xxx`prefixes should be gone.